# discord Permission Errors

Tags: permissions

I installed discord according to these instructions:

https://blog.ubuntu.com/2017/05/04/discord-is-now-available-as-a-snap-for-ubuntu-and-other-distributions

With the exception that I did not install snap because it came with my Ubuntu 18.04 installation. It was already there.

An attempt to run discord gets these errors:

> me@ubuntu:$ discord 2019/01/02 03:08:47.093952 cmd_run.go:835:
>   WARNING: cannot create user data directory: cannot create
>   "/home/me/snap/discord/82": mkdir /home/stephen/snap/discord:
>   permission denied cannot create user data directory:
>   /home/me/snap/discord/82: Permission denied

What do I need to do to solve these permission errors?

```
me@ubuntu:~$ ls -l ~/snap
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Dec 15 04:40 evince
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Dec 15 04:33 inkscape
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 15 04:40 libreoffice
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 15 04:40 okular
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Dec 15 04:40 termius-app

me@ubuntu:~$ ls -l ~/man
ls: cannot access '/home/me/man': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please run `ls -l ~/snap` and `ls -l ~/man` and add to your post!

Comment: please see: [How to accept an answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your update use this to fix those errors by setting the owner of the snap directory to yours:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/snap
```

Now run discord again, it should be able to create those directories and or files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That chown command eliminated the directory errors. But when I enter the command "discord" in the Terminal Emulator nothing happens. The Discord window does not open.  I can see it runs because the cursor goes to the next line without a prompt. To end it I use Ctrl C.

Comment: It is working. I did not realize it at first because it took far longer than expected to start up. When I waited long enough discord did open its window in the desktop.Thanks for your help :).

Comment: Great. You can accept the answer by clicking the check icon by it.

Comment: Tried this, but it's not an ownership problem here. I see the directory, and I own it, but `/var/lib/snapd/snaps/discord_86.snap on /snap/discord/86 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)` so it is read-only.

Comment: Please kindly ask a new question if you have one @Bram!